# kubernetes ingress-nginx ignore special characters in path

Tags: kubernetes, ingress-nginx

I'm trying to have a rule listening to a specific path containing a dollar sign like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: metadata-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: public
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.com
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/v2/$metadata
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: busybox
            port:
              number: 8280
```

I don't want any url rewrite or anything fancy, just want this specific path to be caught and forwarded to this service.

Without the "$" it works.

I thought disabling regex with `use-regex: "false"` would fix it, but no.

I also tried using the url encoded value for $ : %24metadata but it doesn't help either.

I also tried to use "exact" instead of "prefix" as the pathType but no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem, but I thought I walk through my test setup and you can tell me if anything is different. For the purpose of testing different paths, I have two deployments using the [`traefik/whoami`](https://hub.docker.com/r/traefik/whoami) image (this just provides a useful endpoint that shows us -- among other things -- the hostname and path involved in the request).

That looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: example
    component: app1
  name: example-app1
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: example
    component: app1

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: example
    component: app2
  name: example-app2
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: example
    component: app2

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: example
    component: app1
  name: example-app1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
      component: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example
        component: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker.io/traefik/whoami:latest
        name: whoami
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: example
    component: app2
  name: example-app2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
      component: app2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example
        component: app2
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker.io/traefik/whoami:latest
        name: whoami
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
```

I've also deployed the following Ingress resource, which looks mostly like yours, except I've added a second `paths` config so that we can compare requests that match `/api/v2/$metadata` vs those that do not:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: house
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: example
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: example.apps.infra.house
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: example-app1
            port:
              name: http
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: example-app2
            port:
              name: http
        path: /api/v2/$metadata
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.apps.infra.house
    secretName: example-cert
```

With these resources in place, a request to `https://example.apps.infra.house/` goes to `app1`:

```
$ curl -s https://example.apps.infra.house/ | grep Hostname
Hostname: example-app1-596fcf48bd-dqhvc
```

Whereas a request to `https://example.apps.infra.house/api/v2/$metadata` goes to `app2`:

```
$ curl -s https://example.apps.infra.house/api/v2/\$metadata | grep Hostname
Hostname: example-app2-8675dc9b45-6hg7l
```

So that all seems to work.

---

We can, if we are so inclined, examine the nginx configuration that results from that Ingress. On my system, the nginx ingress controller runs in the `nginx-ingress` namespace:

```
$ kubectl -n nginx-ingress get deploy
NAME                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           8d
```

The configuration lives in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in the container. We can `cat` the file to stdout and look for the relevant directives:

```
$ kubectl -n nginx-ingress exec deploy/ingress-nginx-controller cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
...
                location /api/v2/$metadata/ {
                ...
                }
...
```

---

Based on your comment, the following seems to work:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$2"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: house
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - example.apps.infra.house
      secretName: example-cert
  rules:
  - host: example.apps.infra.house
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: example-app1
            port:
              name: http

      # Note the use of single quotes (') here; this is
      # important; using double quotes we would need to
      # write `\\$` instead of `\$`.
      - path: '/api/v2/\$metadata'
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: example-app2
            port:
              name: http
```

The resulting `location` directives look like:

```
location ~* "^/api/v2/\$metadata" {
...
}
location ~* "^/app1(/|$)(.*)" {
...
}
```

And a request for the `$metadata` path succeeds.

Comment: Thank you very much for that detailed answer. I fiddled around my problem a bit more and it seems that the issue occurs only if I have a second ingress resource that have the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation. Even if the rules doesn't matches, it gets prioritized even for the route of my other ingress with the $ sign.

Comment: I checked a diff of the resulting `nginx.conf`. As soon as ANY ingress resource have the annotation, no matter what path it haves as a rule or where it redirect, ALL the "location" parts of the nginx config get replaced from `location = /...` to `location ~* "^/..."`

Comment: Are your ingress resources using the same hostname? I've posted an update to the answer that I think resolves the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much again. It works by using single quotes and escaping the $ with a \. Is this pattern documented somewhere? Also, don't you think it's a bit weird that rules in an ingress that do not use a certain annotation get influenced by a different external one that do? It feels a bit like a bug to me, especially that they are separate entries in the nginx.conf file. I can see it causing problem in a situation like someone installing a new helm chart including its own ingress resource in a cluster and it would break a completely different one and end up causing confusion.

Comment: Re: "Is this pattern documented somewhere?", the `\ ` character is standard syntax for escaping regex metacharacters like `^`, `$`, etc. And the use of single quotes vs double quotes in YAML is part of the YAML spec (https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#732-single-quoted-style). I agree that the behavior of the nginx operator seems a bit surprising.